# Проблема с циклом С++

Tags: c++, while

Как сделать выход из цикла? Перепробовал все вариант. В дебаге он почему то после вывода "Try again?" , делает его бесконечно.

```
int main() {
    int ch = getch();
    char buffer[10] = {0};
    do{
        buffer[10] = {0};
        int number = 0;
        cin >> number;
        int res = CheckNumber(number);
        if (res != 0) {
            Worker(number);
        }else{
            cout << "Is not number!";
            if(ch == 'q'){
                break;
            }
        }
    }while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buffer[10] = {0}`? Как это у вас откомпилировалось?

Comment: Не знаю) Я пытался там массив обнулять (в плюсах не силен, так как привык работать с строками)

Comment: А почему вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу массива за его пределами? Индекса 10 у вас не существует.

Comment: Да какая разница, у меня есть бесконечный цикл. Если введено не число и я хочу чтобы после вывода Is not number, функция запустилась по новой. А она просто берет и бесконечно выводит это сообщение и не доходит до cin по новой.

Comment: Вы не знаете, что такое undefined behaviour, поэтому не видите разницы. Но это не значит, что её нет.

Comment: А ещё вы неправильно проверяете ввод на правильность.

Comment: Опишите лучше словами, что должен делать ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

Отдебажьте и проверьте получаемые значения ch, он никогда не заходит в if, вот и зациклился

пример:

```
int q; 
cout << "Введите число:"; 
cin >> q; 
func(q) void func(int q) { 
    /*что то проверяет и делает*/ 
    return; 
    else { 
        std::cout << "Введите число:"; 
        std::cin >> q;
        func(q);
    }
```

Comment: Да заметил, исправил все равно не понятный цикл идет. Можете кинуть адекватный пример. Чтобы программа делала рекурсию и вновь требовалось вводить число. (А она выводит постоянно Is not a number)

Comment: int q; cout << "Введите число:"; cin >> q; func(q) void func(int q) { /*что то проверяет и делает*/ return; else { std::cout << "Введите число:"; std::cin >> q; func(q);}

Comment: Отформатировал пример кода из вашего комментария. Что-то с ним не так )

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что нехорошо использовать одновременно `getch` и `cin`. Это как одновременно войти в две двери...

Допустим, вы ввели что-то в `ch`. Что дальше? Дальше вы пытаетесь считать число из `cin` и обработать. Допустим, что-то ввелось... Вы обрабатываете. Если `res` число, идете на следующий цикл, нет - вывод, что не число. Проверка - ЧЕГО? `ch` вы ввели **до цикла**. Вряд ли ввели `q` - так что цикл идет на следующую итерацию... И так до бесконечности - `ch` не изменяется!

Только вот у вас при этом присваиванием `buf[10]` еще и память оказывается испорченной, учтите это. Вы пишете *за границей* массива...

Answer (score 0):

так можно

`

```
      int main() {
        int ch = getch();
        char buffer[10] = {0};

        switch (o) {
            case 'q':
            exit(0)'
            default: {
                buffer[10] = {0};
                int number = 0;
                cin >> number;
                int res = CheckNumber(number);
                if (res != 0) {
                    Worker(number);
                }else{
                    cout << "Is not number!";
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    int main() {
        int ch = getch();
        char buffer[10] = {0};
        while ((ch = getch()) != 'q')
            buffer[10] = {0};
            int number = 0;
            cin >> number;
            int res = CheckNumber(number);
            if (res != 0) {
                Worker(number);
            }else{
                cout << "Is not number!";
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

`

Comment: И что вы получите, если нужно будет вводить очередное число? Съеденную цифру?

Comment: получишь ввод нового символа на вход

Comment: Отнюдь. Вы ввели число. `Worker` выдало что-то там, и что дальше? Вы **не можете** сразу вводить число, потому что первое нажатие будет "съедено"...